# How to place button without spaces?

Tags: css

I need to place button at left side of a panel without any spaces.

i do it like this:

```
<p:panel style="padding-left:0;border:0">
    <p:commandButton .../>
</p:panel>
```

but I see in browser instruments that my content is in another inner div and it has default style settings:

```
<div id="A7058:form:j_idt212" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="padding-left:0;border:0">
    <div id="A7058:form:j_idt212_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">
        <button id="A7058:form:content">...</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

so my button doesn't go left as I want to.
How to place button at left side?

Comment: I suggest using the browser tools to see exactly where the space is being added.

Comment: try resetting the `margin`, also `position: absolute` may need since you have it innerdiv

Comment: @Mike I know exact place. A7058:form:j_idt212_content, but I don't know how to control it's style. It uses default one.

Comment: @user1671639 I tried setting margin in panel and in button it doesn't help. Yes, margin of button and panel changes, but this generated <div> ignores style settings of them.

Comment: @330xi Oh, can you setup a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, white space is meaningful, and is by default collapsed down to a single space. You can modify your markup to remove any white space, but this often results in code that isn't very readable. Commenting out white space is another possibility. You can also use `font-size: 0` in your CSS to force text nodes (including white space) to occupy no physical space, then apply a second font-size declaration on child elements that should display text.

Space may also come from margins, padding or borders. Use your browser's developer tools to investigate where the space is coming from.

Comment: *Some* white space is meaningful.  Space between inline elements and/or text nodes, primarily.  Blocks tend not to show whitespace at their beginning or end, though, for example.